# FileLoadException Access is denied when running Docker Compose project in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: docker, docker-compose, visual-studio-2019

I have a multi-project solution using Docker Compose that I work on in Visual Studio 2019 using .NET Core 2.2. Until this morning it has worked fine. All of a sudden I'm getting the following error when I try and run the project.

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileLoadException' occurred in Unknown Module.: 'Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. Access is denied.'
```

There have been a couple of Windows updates in the last day or so (KB4540673 and KB4537572). I believe this is a Visual Studio issue as I ran the project using Docker Compose directly from the command line and it worked fine. It also worked fine when I tested a deployment to a staging environment. I've tried the following:

- Update Visual Studio
- Repair Visual Studio
- Uninstall/Reinstall Visual Studio
- Uninstall/Reinstall Docker
- Removed/Re-added shared drive in Docker
- Removed/Reinstalled .NET Core SDK 2.2
- A few other things I'm forgetting

Any thoughts on what might be causing this or what else I can try?

Comment: Same issue here after updating to the latest VS. Super disappointing.

Comment: I rolled back to 16.4.5 and the issue remained, so I'm wondering if it is related to a Windows Update change.

Comment: Same issue here after updating to 2.2.0.4. docker-compose can be started in release mode anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem.
After uninstalling docker desktop 2.2.0.4 and installing 2.2.0.3 the problem disappeared. (Burned me one day...)

Comment: Yep, this fixed it for me too. Thanks! I was having a bunch of other Docker issues too, like my containers not getting built with the latest code changes and things like that. Hopefully rolling back to 2.2.0.3 will fix that too. The weird thing is that I have 2.2.0.4 on another machine and didn't have any of these problems.